# LINQ expression translation issue with GroupBy and where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am trying to get all items in database that have a duplicate owner. My first method returns their count and works without any issue:

```
public int GetUsersWithMultipleItemsCount()
{
    return GetItemsSecureAsync().Result
        .Where(item => item.OwnerId != null)
        .GroupBy(item => item.OwnerId)
        .Count(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1);
}
```

But the method to actually get a list of them fails to translate:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid?, ItemType>> GetItemsWithDuplicateOwners()
{
    return GetItemsSecureAsync().Result
        .Where(item => item.OwnerId != null)
        .GroupBy(item => item.OwnerId)
        .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
        .ToList();
}
```

How can I modify this to work without needing client-side evaluation? I would rather not slow down my app because of such insignificant feature.

Edit: I though the solution worked but now it is failing again despite the SelectMany clause. I have created a small extension function for this purpose:

```
public static IQueryable<T> NonDistinct<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(r => r);
}
```

It seems there is an issue with EF Core7 related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because of `ToList()`

Use `SelectMany()` first

```
public IEnumerable<ItemType> GetItemsWithDuplicateOwners()
{
    var duplicates = GetItemsSecureAsync().Result
                     .Where(item => item.OwnerId != null)
                     .GroupBy(item => item.OwnerId)
                     .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1);

    var query = duplicates.SelectMany(grouping => grouping);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems I spoke too soon. There seems to be an issue currently with the groupby clause.